# Date picker not showing when new field is generated [jquery]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am unable to get the date picker function whenever a new field is generated , please what tweak is needed to fix this ?

I have no knowledge of javascript I am currently building this on flask

basically what I am trying to get is :
upon clicking on the add new position button a new field is generated , I want this field to function just the same way the initial field works (i.e the date pickers should show)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_input_fields = 10;
  var add_input = $('.add-input');
  var input_wrapper = $('.input-wrapper');
  var new_input = '<div class="col-lg-12  "><br><div class="col-md-12 select-pane "><label class="labels">Department</label><select \
          class="form-control -sm h-50 w-100 " name="department" aria-label="Select Filter">\
          <option>finace</option><option>music</option></select></div><div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Position Held \
            </label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter Position" name="positions"></div>\
        <div class="col-lg-12"><label class="labels">From</label><input type="text" name="From" id="From" class="form-control" \
          placeholder="From Date" /></div><div class="col-lg-12"><label class="labels">To</label><input type="text" name="to" \
            id="to" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" /></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="col-lg-12 remove-input" title="Remove input"><button type="button" name="position_button">Remove</button></a></div>';

  var add_input_count = 1;
  $(add_input).click(function() {
    if (add_input_count < max_input_fields) {
      add_input_count++;
      $(input_wrapper).append(new_input);
    }
  });
  $(input_wrapper).on('click', '.remove-input', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    add_input_count--;
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
  $(function() {
    $("#From").datepicker();
    $("#to").datepicker();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="p-3 py-5">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center experience">
      <div class="col-lg-12  ">
        <h5>Add Previous Positions Held</h5>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12 select-pane "><label class="labels">Department</label>
          <select class="form-control -sm h-50 w-100 " name="department" aria-label="Select Filter">
            <option>finace</option>
            <option>music</option>

          </select>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Position Held</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter Position" name="positions"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="labels">From</label>
          <input type="text" name="From" id="From" class="form-control" placeholder="From Date" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="labels">To</label>
          <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" />
          <br>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="col-lg-12 add-input" title="Add input"><button type="button" name="position_button">Add more positions</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id's in html should be unique, if you want multiple none unique elements use class.

Below is a potential solution implemented by changing the id of new input blocks.

```
var id_index = 2; //Id for from and to

$(document).ready(function() {

    var max_input_fields = 10;
    var add_input = $('.add-input');
    var input_wrapper = $('.input-wrapper');

    var add_input_count = 1;

    $(add_input).click(function() {
        if (add_input_count < max_input_fields) {
            
            //Moved so that the from and two id can change
            
            var new_input = '<div class="col-lg-12"><br><div class="col-md-12 select-pane "><label class="labels">Department</label><select \
                  class="form-control -sm h-50 w-100 " name="department" aria-label="Select Filter">\
                  <option>finace</option><option>music</option></select></div><div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Position Held \
                    </label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter Position" name="positions"></div>\
                <div class="col-lg-12"><label class="labels">From</label><input type="text" name="From" id="From' + id_index + '" class="form-control" \
                  placeholder="From Date" /></div><div class="col-lg-12"><label class="labels">To</label><input type="text" name="to" \
                    id="to' + id_index + '" class="form-control" placeholder="To Date" /></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="col-lg-12 remove-input" title="Remove input"><button type="button" name="position_button">Remove</button></a></div>';

            
            add_input_count++;
                            
            $(input_wrapper).append(new_input);
            
            $("#From" + id_index).datepicker(); //Apply datetime
            $("#to" + id_index).datepicker();
            
            id_index++; //Increment id 
        }
    });
  
    $(input_wrapper).on('click', '.remove-input', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        add_input_count--;
    });
  
    //Removed $(document).ready as its redundant
    
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    });
  
    $("#From").datepicker();
    $("#to").datepicker();

});
```

Comment: well noted it worked fine , thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_input_fields = 10;
  var add_input = $('.add-input');
  var input_wrapper = $('.input-wrapper');
  var new_input = '<div class="col-lg-12  "><br><div class="col-md-12 select-pane "><label class="labels">Department</label><select \
          class="form-control -sm h-50 w-100 " name="department" aria-label="Select Filter">\
          <option>finace</option><option>music</option></select></div><div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Position Held \
            </label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter Position" name="positions"></div>\
        <div class="col-lg-12"><label class="labels">From</label><input type="text" name="From"  class="form-control datepicker" \
          placeholder="From Date" /></div><div class="col-lg-12"><label class="labels">To</label><input type="text" name="to" \
            class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="To Date" /></div><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="col-lg-12 remove-input" title="Remove input"><button type="button" name="position_button">Remove</button></a></div>';

  var add_input_count = 1;
  $(add_input).click(function() {
    if (add_input_count < max_input_fields) {
      add_input_count++;
      $(input_wrapper).append(new_input);
    }
  });
  $(input_wrapper).on('click', '.remove-input', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    add_input_count--;
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.datepicker.setDefaults({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
  });
  $(function() {
   $(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function(event){
      $(event.target).datepicker().datepicker("show");
   });
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="p-3 py-5">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center experience">
      <div class="col-lg-12  ">
        <h5>Add Previous Positions Held</h5>
        <br>
        <div class="col-md-12 select-pane "><label class="labels">Department</label>
          <select class="form-control -sm h-50 w-100 " name="department" aria-label="Select Filter">
            <option>finace</option>
            <option>music</option>

          </select>
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-12"><label class="labels">Position Held</label><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter Position" name="positions"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="labels">From</label>
          <input type="text" name="From"  class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="From Date" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <label class="labels">To</label>
          <input type="text" name="to"  class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="To Date" />
          <br>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="col-lg-12 add-input" title="Add input"><button type="button" name="position_button">Add more positions</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You cannot reuse the same id in a html document. So I removed the id="From" and id="to" from the html

Since you are generating dynamic element, jQuery does not recognize it. So the click is captured on document level and datepicker is assigned to the element which has "datepicker" as class. You can find the class name added as class="datepicker" on your from and to input boxes